# Please check out the Word document before editing it in word online in Sharepoint

Tags: word, online

Please look at the picture. Is this something related to the record class or something? Please help

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Just making sure you know how to [check out documents](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Check-a-file-in-or-out-of-a-SharePoint-library-361EA6E1-41E8-49D3-842C-C26D79A2506F)

> In Word, click the Microsoft Office Button, click Server, and then click Check Out.

Comment: Hi Andy,
Thanks for your reply. I figured that out. Really appreciate that